# Speed up Listview load and sort it

Tags: java, android, listview

I have small Android app, but the Sqlite database is big, and the form loading is slow. How Can I speed up Listview load and sort it by name?

My code is here:

```
   public void nameload(){
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    db = openOrCreateDatabase(Adatbazis, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor Namecursor = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT name from Table WHERE ztr='"+ztrcode+"'", null);
    Namecursor.moveToFirst();

    String name = "";

    while (!Namecursor.isAfterLast()) {
        name = "" + Namecursor.getString(Namecursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        names.add(name);
        Namecursor.moveToNext();

    }


    //A tömb elemeinek betöltése a UI-ba
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            names);


    namelist.setAdapter(adapter1);

    Namecursor.close();
}
```

Thank you for help me :)

Comment: use `SimpleCursorAdapter`, and not `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: Can you write me a code? I'm junior school developer :)

Comment: just create `SimpleCursorAdapter` and pass it to `setAdapter` method

Comment: you can fetch your data from database before the screen you want tos show it

Answer (score 0):

Always remember Closing the cursor after `setAdapter()` may prevent the adapter from accessing the data which makes the loading slow.

So move your `Namecursor.close();` after the loop, before `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(..)`